# Removing an outer table without harming internal tables?

Tags: php, html

I help administer a website that pulls content for a few of its pages from a parent site.  We don't have any control over the formatting at the parent site and we are obliged to fetch the content (rather than copy/pasting) to avoid having multiple versions of the same content across different sites.

The content of these pages is held in a table. I have used simple regex to remove most of the stuff we don't need and to imporve the formatting some.  The current string, after processing, looks like this:

```
<table class='pageSetup'>    
   <tbody>
     <tr>
      <td>
         <!--Lots of content here, including child tables-->
      </td>
     </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to strip away that outer table (and all of its child table-related tags) without harming the content in that td, which does contain a table.

I have access to PHP.  I'm guessing that I want to use DOM to do this somehow, but I don't have very much experience with DOM.

Can anyone get me pointed in the right direction?  I tinkered with the problem and ran into brick walls. I don't have any of that code (I deleted it in frustration last night).

Thanks!

Comment: @Peter: Could you please clarify what you've said?  I am wide open to hearing that the approach I want to take is wrong.  I have no idea what you're telling me I'm doing wrong, though.  Could you please express your concerns in a constructive and clear way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

try to load your whole html content in an object then extract ONLY the part you need

1. Check this [Quick Start](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm#section_quickstart) to know how to load your hmtl in an object
2. then search your content as:

   > $ret = $html->find('table[class=pageSetup] tbody tr td', 0);
3. at the end, access the code you need as:

   > $ret->innertext

I hope this help